# Ubuntu find command and printf argument

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to search a file which is 1033 bytes size. After half hour googling I find a command which show all file name and size inside the current directory.

```
find -printf 'Name: %16f Size: %6s\n'
```

---

How `%16f` and `%6s` show the name and file size?

Comment: Maybe a question for http://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: the find tool is rather powerful, see http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to search a file which is 1033 bytes size.

You can say:

```
find . -type f -size 1033c
```

---

`%f` and `%s` are directives for the `printf` option:

```
          %f     File's name with any leading  directories  removed  (only
                 the last element).

          %s     File's size in bytes.
```

Saying `%16f` would pad the filename; be warned that the output might be *truncated* if the filename exceeds 16 characters.

Comment: oh! this is unlike C. I thought I was to pass those data. thanks

Comment: Is there a type directive exists??

Comment: `-type` is referred to as a `predicate`.

Comment: Maybe try reading the manual page?  @ShinTakezou's answer has a good link.